# Twilio sets worker to offline after a call is not answered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have a task router with some workers, when there is an incoming call and the worker does not answer the call, then the worker is been updated, and the status is been set to offline. Can I avoid that and keep the worker in the available activity state?

```
worker.on 'activity.update', @_onWorkerActivityUpdated
```

Answer (score 1):

[Configuring Default Activities for Worker State Transitions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/activity#configuring-default-activities-for-worker-state-transitions)

If a Reservation times out, the Worker is placed in the TimeoutActivity identified by the Workspace. By default this is Offline.

[image]

Comment: Awesome Alan, that solved my issue...! thx..